# Is it possible to plot a loss, accuracy or validation curve while using tflearn instead of using tensorboard?

Tags: python, tflearn

I am using tflearn, and I am trying to plot some curves by using mathplotlib. I am not using tf.Session (There is an example on that but I cant use that solution) and I don't want to visualise it in tensorboard.

I was wondering if there was a way. Would it be possible to get the network structure as well somehow?

thank you